# is it possible to call db_set_active() in another php file out of .module file

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I'am trying to interact with an external database in other php file out of my_module.module file,but I get this error :

```
Call to undefined function db_set_active()
```

I tried this :

```
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_DATABASE);
db_set_active('my_external_db');
```

but in vain.

Any help please

Edit:

My .php file was called withen a jQuery.ajax as url as bellow:

```
pathurl="sites/all/modules/MyModule/includes/treeviewPhpAPI.php";
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling you PHP script directly and not passing by Drupal bootstrapping (i.e.: page callback), you need to include `bootstrap.inc` (just like `cron.php` is doing)

```
if (!defined('DRUPAL_ROOT')) {
    define('DRUPAL_ROOT', dirname(__FILE__));
    chdir(DRUPAL_ROOT);
}

include_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_DATABASE);

db_set_active('my_external_db');
```

Comment: No, actually my .php file is under my module/includes/

Comment: And how is the php file called ? Do you just do an include of it ?

Comment: I've edited my answer, you should include bootstrap in your php script

Comment: `define('DRUPAL_ROOT', dirname(__FILE__))`  make DRUPAL_ROOT as my module root and I just need where drupal is installed, here is my try : `include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. 'Drupal/includes/bootstrap.inc');
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_DATABASE);` it works it knows the file but it gives: use of undefined constant DRUPAL_ROOT  in bootstrap.inc !!!

Comment: solved `if (!defined('DRUPAL_ROOT')) {
    define('DRUPAL_ROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. 'DrupalFolder');
    chdir(DRUPAL_ROOT);
}
include_once(DRUPAL_ROOT.'/includes/bootstrap.inc');
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_DATABASE);`  thank you Mike for your time :) .